# create post with main category and other categories from admin panel

Tags: categories

I want to add functionality in admin panel for add / edit post with selection like main category and other category. Main category will be used to generate permalink of particular post.

Default wordpress uses alphabetical order of category for generate permalink.

Once permalink will be generated for particular post, that permalink should not be changed when post will be updated.

I want to do this just because of SEO purpose.

Please suggest me if anyone has solution.
Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide an example in your question

Comment: I want to allow user to have functionality like select category for generate permalink with which category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution.

I have used "[WP Category Permalink](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-category-permalink/)" plugin to solve generate post permalink issue.